# Consulta com JPA filtrando por Lista de entidade

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria

Estou realizando um sistema em **Java** utilizando **SpringBoot** e **JPA**, sendo de gerenciamento de eventos e possuo duas entidades: `Inscricao` e `HorarioAtividade`.

Elas possuem um relacionamento *Many To Many*, com minha classe `Inscricao` possuindo uma lista de `HorarioAtividades` com as atividades de cada inscricao e a Classe `HorarioAtividade` possuindo uma lista de Inscricoes com as inscricoes daquela atividade.

A classe `Inscricao` também possui um atributo `situacao` que é do tipo `enum`, ex.

```
SituacaoInscricao.RESERVADA
SituacaoInscricao.CONFIRMADA
SituacaoInscricao.AG_PAGAMENTO
```

Quando faço um `findAll` no repositório de `HorarioAtividade`, ele traz as horarioAtividades com a lista de inscrições todas certinhas automaticamente por meio do relacionamento delas.

O problema que não consigo resolver é:

Preciso buscar todos os `HorarioAtividade` de minha base, só que está trazendo apenas as inscrições que estão confirmadas e aguardando pagamento.

Já tentei com `join fetch`, mas ele acaba misturando tudo e a *query* não fica correta.

Procurei sobre a **Criteria api**, mas não entendi como resolver meu problema com ela.

Comment: Seria interessante por o código na pergunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Preciso buscar todos os `HorarioAtividade` de minha base, só que está trazendo apenas as inscrições que estão confirmadas e aguardando pagamento.
>
> Já tentei com `join fetch`, mas ele acaba misturando tudo e a *query* não fica correta.

Provavelmente você caiu em uma "pegadinha" do JPA: você **não deve usar** `WHERE` em um `JOIN FETCH`.

No seu exemplo, quando isto ocorre, ele incorretamente retorna todos os `HorarioAtividade` que tem inscrições confirmadas (ou aguardando pagamento) mas removerá todas as inscrições que não obedecem o mesmo filtro. Assim, se você tem um `HorarioAtividade` com 3 inscrições no banco, uma delas sendo `CONFIRMADA`, as outras duas não irão ser retornadas (e você esperaria que fosse).

Se quer retornar todas as inscrições de um horário de atividade e aplicar um `WHERE` nelas, trazendo as demais inscrições que não se enquadram no mesmo filtro mas pertencem ao mesmo horário de atividade, você precisa de dois JOINs: um para o `WHERE` e outro para o `JOIN FETCH`.

> Preciso buscar todos os HorarioAtividade de minha base, SÓ QUE trazendo apenas as inscrições que estão Confirmadas e aguardando pagamento.

O JPQL para este caso seria algo assim:

```
SELECT ha FROM HorarioAtividade ha 
JOIN ha.inscricoes insc
FETCH JOIN ha.inscricoes
WHERE insc.situacao = 'CONFIRMADA' OR insc.situacao = 'AG_PAGAMENTO'
```